# Loading html tag multiple times using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

How do I load the below html tag multiple times on a webpage using angular js. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

```
<md-whiteframe class="md-whiteframe-10dp" flex="25" layout layout-align="center center"> <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Add To Cart</md-button> </md-whiteframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do step by step

Step 1: Define template

```
var template = angular.element('<md-whiteframe class="md-whiteframe-10dp" flex="25" layout layout-align="center center"> <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">Add To Cart</md-button> </md-whiteframe>');
```

Step 2: Create function via two paras: (templateStr,loopTime) to combine loopTime

This function return loopTime of HTML templateStr

Hope it helps.